# flutter text editing controller listview.builder

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-listview, texteditingcontroller

I want the page to display a list of social media apps where the user can input their usernames/ details. I want to be able to extract this input data along with the app name and logo (preferably as a JSON file) to be able to create them into buttons which lead to the respective app and profile.

For this I've created a list of List Tiles using the listview.builder (from a separate list which has the list of apps and logo that I want to include) and have added a TextField to each List Tile using the subtitle function.

Please would you be able to help me add the TextEditing Controller to each item of the list and extract a file with the text input, appname and logo.

Please note: the applist is a list which contains the appname, hint text of the TextField and image of the logo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:applist/apps.dart';

class AppList extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppListState createState() => _AppListState();
}

class _AppListState extends State<AppList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My list of apps'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: apps.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(apps[index].appname),
                        leading: SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          child: Image.asset(apps[index].image),
                        ),
                        subtitle: TextField(
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(hintText: (apps[index].hint)),
                        ),
                      );
                    }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1- you need to define `TextEditingConrtoller` field variable:

```dart
late  TextEditingController textEditingController ;
```

2- initialize the field variable in `initState`

```dart
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  }
```

3- then Initialize your `TextField` the th e controller

```dart
TextField(
   controller:textEditingController ,
)
```

- your final code should be like this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:applist/apps.dart';

class AppList extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppListState createState() => _AppListState();
}

class _AppListState extends State<AppList> {
late  TextEditingController textEditingController ;   // <--
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textEditingController = TextEditingController(); // <--
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My list of apps'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: apps.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(apps[index].appname),
                        leading: SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          child: Image.asset(apps[index].image),
                        ),
                        subtitle: TextField(
                          controller:textEditingController , // <--
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(hintText: (apps[index].hint)),
                        ),
                      );
                    }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not getting errors anymore so that's good but how do I create the textediting controller unique for each textfield on the list? At the moment when I edit one, all of the other texfields reciprocate. Your advice/ help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: instead of one text controller, you need a pre-initialized `List` of controllers 
if the index is enough to distinguish between each controller, if not use `Map` instead
```dart
late final List<TextEditingController> controllers;
```
init each one 
```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  final numberOfControllers = 100;
  controllers =
      List.generate(numberOfControllers, (index) => TextEditingController());
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make each app have a unique id (if only the app name isn't unique).

Create a map of TextEditingController

```
Map<String, TextEditingController> _textControllers = new Map();
```

Add a new TextEditingController for each of your apps with its **unique name or id** as the key

```
apps.forEach((app) => textControllers[app.id] = new TextEditingController());
```

Finally you can use it in your ListViewBuilder like so..

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: apps.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => TextFormField(
            controller: _textControllers[apps[index].id],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use unique controllers for text fields.
You should use a model that will have a controller and other data.
Example of a model using "freezed"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
part 'controller_model.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class ControllerModel with _$ControllerModel {
  const factory ControllerModel({
    required String name,
    required TextEditingController controller,
  }) = _ControllerModel;
}
```